# Why my scrapy ouput result is array

Tags: python, scrapy

Scrapy seems will format my output from dict to array while all i need was just string object.The output:

```html
{"title": ["some title some title"], "url": ["https://www.example.com/"], "upDate": ["2017/06/07 10:23:00"]}
```

and the code:

```html
    l = ItemLoader(item=RoomInfoItem(), response=response)
    updateStr = '2017-' + res.css('td[class="time"]::text').extract_first() 
    l.add_value('upDate', upDateStr)
    ownerurl = response.css('span[class="from"] a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    l.add_value('ownerUrl', ownerurl)
    title = response.css('div[id="content"] h1::text').extract_first()
    l.add_value('title', title)
    yield l.load_item()
```

the scrapy resource it seems like when add new value to item, scrapy will turn the argument to  an iterable by scrapy.utils.misc.arg_to_iter().
If there any other method can add values to the items while not change the value data struct?
The output i want may look like this:

```html
{"title": "some title some title", "url": "https://www.example.com/", "upDate": "2017/06/07 10:23:00"}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, i solve this problem by give up use the ItemLoader object. I use the item directly which will not change my data struct automatic. 
The code :

```html
item=RoomInfoItem()
item['url'] = resUrl
item['upDate'] = upDateStr
item['title'] = title
yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

It's standart behaviour of ItemLoader object.
For change it you should create child Object and use *default_output_processor = TakeFirst()*

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join

    ... YOUR CODE...

    l = YourLoader(item=RoomInfoItem(), response=response)

class YourLoader(ItemLoader):

    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

    title_in = MapCompose(unicode.title)
    url_in = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
```

You can check more in scrapy docs [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#input-and-output-processors).